# Redux-form: Can't use ternary operator because object is undefined when rendering

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am using redux-form to let the user click on pictures (to activate hidden checkboxes). Everything works fine, except that I want to change the css when a pic was clicked. I use a ternary operator for this, which should listen to the value of the checkbox. The problem I have is that when the component initially renders, productValues.apps[product.name] returns undefined. I tried setting an initialValue with false, but that did not work either. I really don't know how to solve this problem. Here are the checkboxes:

```
   {
      products.products.map(product => {
        return(
          <div className={ `col-xs-2 ${productValues.apps[product.name] ? "app-checked" : "app-container"}` }
               key={ product.id }>
            <label htmlFor={ product.name }>
              <img className="app-circle"
                   src={ product.image } alt={ product.title }
                   data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title={ product.title }/>

              <Field name={ `apps[${product.name}]` } className="hidden"
                    component="input" type="checkbox" id={ product.name }/>
            </label>
          </div>
        );
      })
    }
```

and here the selector I use to get the data of the checkbox:
const selector = formValueSelector('UserCreationForm');

```
UserCreationPageThree = connect(
  state => {
    const productValues = selector(state, ...state.products.products.map(product => `apps[${product.name}]`));

    return { productValues }
  }
)(UserCreationPageThree)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add conditions like -

{(productValues && productValues.apps && productValues.apps[product.name]) ? "app-checked" : "app-container"}

**update as for request**
there are difference between `not exists` and `undefined` on `Javascript World`. `undefined` means something is defined but the value is not defined.

i.e.
If I define a variable as-

***file_1.js***

```
var x;
console.log(x); // its will display undefined on console.
```

Now-

***file_2.js***

```
console.log(x); // it will throw error on 'strict mode' but on non `strict mode` javascript engine will first define `x` for you then console.log undefined.
```

**In your case-**

```
productValues.apps[product.name] does not exists;
```

Comment: This totally worked. Thanks. But I don't really understand why it doesn't drop the same error here. I mean, productValues.apps[product.name] should still be undefined when rendering. Why doesn't he bother in this combined condition? Would u be so kind to explain?

Comment: I edited my answer little. I hope you will understand.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. Your effort is very much appreciated.